# VBA: copy paste ranges from array

Tags: vba, copy-paste

I have an array that contains the cell locations form a search function.  I would like to display the results of each location in the array along with the subsequent data entry from columns D:P.  Is there an efficient way of doing this?  This is what I have so far but it is not a working code and i would prefer it if it only selected D:P columns instead of an entire row

```
Dim i1 As Integer
Dim Results1() As Variant
Dim p1results As Range
Dim NextRow as Long

   For i1 = LBound(Results1) To UBound(Results1)
        Set p1results = Results1(i1).Value
        p1results.EntireRow.Copy
        Sheets("SearchResult").Select
        NextRow = Range("D65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Cells(NextRow, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    Next i1
```

Comment: You will have to tell us what Results1 exactly contains. Range objects? Strings with location addresses?

Comment: Results1 is supposed to contain the location addresses

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim i1 As Integer
Dim Results1() As Variant
Dim rngDest as Range

Set rngDest = Sheets("SearchResult").Cells(rows.count,4).End(xlUp).Offset(1,-3)

For i1 = LBound(Results1) To UBound(Results1)
        
  Range(Results1(i1)).EntireRow.Copy rngDest
  Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(1,0)
               
Next i1
```

Answer (score 0):

For columns (D:P) Try:

```
Dim i1 As Integer
Dim Results1() As Variant

For i1 = LBound(Results1) To UBound(Results1)
    Sheets("SearchResult").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)(2).Resize(, 13).Value = _
    Range(Results1(i1)).Resize(, 13).Value
Next i1
```

Assuming use dont need formats then its better to avoid using copy.  Copy makes use of the clipboard which is slow.